# Why $http in ng-init is not getting called everytime the view is loaded - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-init, ng-controller

I have modified my question as per my observation.`$http` request on server side is not happening whenever the view is called second or third or so on times  although `initWishList` (**ng-init**) is getting called. The scenario is as below:

I have a **My Account** tab in the nav-bar, which opens a view having options like MyWishlist, My Address etc. When **My wishlist** is clicked for the first time, `$http` request happens, but when I again click on **My Account** (this time I don't see any call on server side when the .html view is loaded) , and then if I click **My Wishlist** , the controller is called but $http isn't called (this time I again dont see any call on server side from `$http`) but I can see the alert **Init Called**

Why so?

```
$scope.initWishList = function(){
    alert('Init called')
    $http.get("/get_wish_list/")
    .success(function (response) {
        $scope.refreshWishList(JSON.parse(response["products_json"]));
    })
    .error(function(){
        console.log('Error');
    });
};
```

Hope I have explained the scenario properly.

Comment: ng-init should be not used. why you don't initate a variable in the scope controller and update it after ?

Comment: @AlainIb Hmm, but why is it not getting called when view is clicked again?

Comment: Can you show HTML of your scenario? `ng-init` gets executed each time the element it is attached to is rendered and compiled by Angular, so it won't matter if the template is retrieved from the server or from cache.

Comment: @tasseKATT: I have updated my question. Have a look now

Comment: That code doesn't help. You need to show the HTML where `ng-init` is used, and how it relates to the nav-bar and views.

Comment: "This directive can be abused to add unnecessary amounts of logic into your templates. There are only a few appropriate uses of ngInit, such as for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below; and for injecting data via server side scripting. Besides these few cases, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope." - from AngularJS's ngInit [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: @tasseKATT: I can surely put my html code but its all working fine. I mean even `ng-init` is getting called properly and I am able to see the alerts. Its just that the `$http` call(which is inside `ng-init`) is not getting triggered.  Do u still want me to put `html` code ?  It'll look messy after that :(

Comment: @JonK: Even when I have removed `ng-init` and have called this function through ` $scope.initWishList();`  , I am still not able to see `$http` call on server end

Comment: No need for HTML if `ng-init` isn't the problem anymore :)

Comment: Open the network tab of the Chrome DevTools and then call `initWishList` twice. You should be able to see if the second call is retrieved from cache.

Comment: @tasseKATT: Awesome. Saw from Firefox. It is showing `/get_wish_list`   **Transferred**  column as `cached`. Thanks

Comment: @tasseKATT: Although I have handled cache issue but I wonder why it is enabled by default ? I mean shouldn't this be disabled in case of `$http` calls as it was picking old data

Comment: When you see a call in the Firefox/Chrome dev tools and it says `cached`, it has nothing to do with Angular. It's the browser that has cached the request. If you cache results with Angular the next call to `$http` would retrieve the result from an in memory object, and there would not be any visible call in dev tools. Not sure if that explains your question or not :)

Answer (score 1):

Controllers gets intialized only once when angular parses ng-controller directive. Since controller is initialized once, ng-init will also run once.

For your satisfaction, add a break point in the your controller on the first line, see when you hit that break point. Are you hitting that break point, every time you click the tab ? If not, ng-init will not be called every time

Comment: I have updated my question with some new findings. Please check now